# What are presidential candidate Iván Duque's main points about the peace deal signed with FARC in Colombia?

Tags: presidential-election, peace-treaty, colombia

Last May 27, there was the first round of the [Colombian presidential election 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombian_presidential_election,_2018). The two politicians that made it to the final round are Iván Duque, rightwinger, and Gustavo Petro, a former guerrilla M-19 head.

Iván Duque has the major support of the former president Álvaro Uribe, who lead the country between 2002 and 2010. Back then, his Minister of Defense was Juan Manuel Santos, who then became the president from 2010 up to 2018.

During Santos's government, a peace deal was signed with the FARC-guerrilla. However, a big portion of the population was against it and, in fact, the [referendum to ratify the deal in 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombian_peace_agreement_referendum,_2016) was held and the result was against that deal.

One of the main leaders against the peace deal was Uribe, who then became a big political enemy of Santos (that is, of his former Minister of Defense). Not being able to run for president again, he has created a party for which is running Iván Duque, the winner of the first leg of the election.

I have been reading about the results in [Colombia elections: rightwinger and former guerrilla head for presidential runoff](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/may/28/colombia-presidential-elections-ivan-duque-gustavo-petro-runoff) and they mention all these things and explain about the differences on how to continue with the peace deal with FARC. However, I cannot find information about **what are Iván Duque's main points about how to proceed with the peace deal?** Does the current deal include any term that allows it to be revoked?